# Problems with my API in Vue.js with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a bookstore app with Vue.js. The books are in this API https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h3vb3, but I can't show them in my HTML with the following function and I don't understand why:

```html
<div id="list-books" v-if="books && books.length">
  <div>Cover page: <strong>{{ books }}</strong></div>
  <div>Details: <strong>{{ books.detalle }}</strong></div>
  <div>Title: <strong>{{books.titulo}}</strong></div>
  <div>Description: <strong >{{books.descripcion}}</strong></div>
  <div>Language: <strong>{{books.idioma}}</strong></div>
</div>
<div class="text-center" v-else> No results! </div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#vue-app",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Ubiqum Bookstore",
      books: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getAPI() {
      axios
        .get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h3vb3")
        .then(response => {
          this.books = response;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("No found!");
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've actually attempted to display the books? Also, this.books should probably = response.data (.data containing the actual json from the API)

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - what is the *problem* here? Errors? Unexpected outputs? What does the template look like?

Comment: Try it with `response.data` if u dont how the response looks like then just `console.log(response)` it, its the easiest way to debugg

Comment: I had the console.log(response) and I didn´t see anything about it in the console, (any error or data) so I don´t understand what is happen, maybe this is not been reading?

Comment: In the html I have, ```<div id="list-books" v-if="books && books.length">
                      <div>Cover page: <strong>{{ books }}</strong></div>
                      <div>Details: <strong>{{ books.detalle }}</strong></div>
                      <div>Title: <strong>{{books.titulo}}</strong></div>
                      <div>Description: <strong >{{books.descripcion}}</strong></div>
                      <div>Language: <strong>{{books.idioma}}</strong></div>
              <div class="text-center" v-else>
                No results!
              </div>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` resolves to a [`Response`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema), which stores the received data in the `data` property. In your code, you've incorrectly set `this.books` to `response`, which is the entire `Response` object. You should instead reference `response.data.books`:

```js
axios.get(...).then(response => this.books = response.data.books)
```

Also, to render a list of items, use [`v-for="book in books"`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) like this:

```html
<div v-for="book in books">
  <div>Details: <strong>{{ book.detalle }}</strong></div>
  <div>Title: <strong>{{ book.titulo }}</strong></div>
  <div>Description: <strong >{{ book.descripcion }}</strong></div>
  <div>Language: <strong>{{ book.idioma }}</strong></div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Ubiqum Bookstore",
      books: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getAPI() {
      axios
        .get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h3vb3")
        .then(response => {
          this.books = response.data.books;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("No found!");
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.book {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
 
<div id="vue-app">
  <button @click="getAPI">Get data from API</button>
  <div id="list-books" class="book" v-if="books" v-for="book in books">
<!--     <div>Cover page: <strong>{{ books }}</strong></div> -->
    <div>Details: <strong>{{ book.detalle }}</strong></div>
    <div>Title: <strong>{{book.titulo}}</strong></div>
    <div>Description: <strong >{{book.descripcion}}</strong></div>
    <div>Language: <strong>{{book.idioma}}</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center" v-else> No results! </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now the code is working but do you know why I can´t see the images for the cover page? They are .png on Json

Comment: Your template shows no references to images. You might want to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you haven't pasted your full code, but you've declared your `getAPI` method, but I don't see where you actually run it.

What I'm missing is something like this:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    title: "Ubiqum Bookstore",
    books: []
  };
},
mounted() {
  this.getAPI();
},
methods: {
  getAPI() {
    ...
  }
}
```

EDIT
See below code snippet. You've made a few more mistakes as well:

- Your books array appeared empty because `this.books = response;` assigned the whole response object to it. The actual data is a bit deeper, hence `this.books = response.data.books;`.
- You missed a `v-for` to loop through your results

```
<div class="book" v-for="book in books">`
...
</div>
```

Working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6bytes/ufbaem0j/8/

Comment: I have writen this new code but the console from Vue.js says that books array is empty

Comment: I've added a working code snippet. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Now the code is working but do you know why I can´t see the images for the cover page? They are .png on Json

Comment: Your `book.portada` and `book.detalle` are links to images. You need to show them as images in your HTML like this: `<div>Cover page: <img :src="book.portada" width="30" /></div>`